# can i create graphic external display for debug purpose?

Tags: objective-c

i have a tree for AI, and game graphics.
i'd like to display the game graphic on iphone simulator or device, and other graphic (tree) in another window like nslogs.
it is possible?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think its not possible, mainly because the iOS SDK and the xCode IDE don't allow you to  simulate a hypothetical dual screen App, perhaps you can achieve your requirements putting two NSViews (or OpenGL views) in your App (like a split screen) and render your graph data to the desired view, game graphics in one view and the tree to the another.